# ASP MVC 4 Routes error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have a problem with my ASP MVC 4 application

here is my known error:

> The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'page' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Index(Int32, Int32, Int32)'

Here is my `RouteConfig.cs`:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "AppareilRoute",
            url: "Appareil/page/{page}/{pageSize}/{triCol}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Appareil", action = "Index", page = "{page}", pageSize = "{pageSize}", triCol = "{triCol}" }
        );

routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

My call:

```
@Html.RouteLink("Appareils", "AppareilRoute", new { page=0, pageSize=50, triCol=0 })
```

The controller receive always nulls values.

I'm so disappointing with this error, I have tried many things, but none works...
Anyone could help me here? Thank you.

Comment: as a first step, try routedebug to see what it tells you is going on:http://haacked.com/archive/2008/03/13/url-routing-debugger.aspx

Comment: Isn't the last MapRoute overriding your AppareilRoute? Try putting all your custom routes after the generic ones.

Comment: It seems that my call doesnt match with my route that what say routedebug.
The route used is the default route, why my request doesn't match ?

Comment: @Kugel Custom routes must go before generic routes. Routes are matched top-down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put integer values as your defaults in the route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
        name: "AppareilRoute",
        url: "Appareil/page/{page}/{pageSize}/{triCol}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Appareil", action = "Index", page = 0, pageSize = 50, triCol = 0 }
    );
```

Comment: How about if you use an ActionLink instead of a RouteLink? `@Html.ActionLink("Index", "Appareil", new { page=0, pageSize=50, triCol=0 })`

Comment: I think the use of page could be causing an issue - does this route change work? `url: "Appareil/pages/{page}/{pageSize}/{triCol}"`

Comment: Doesn't work too
It seems that my call doesnt match with my route that what say routedebug. The route used is the default route, why my request doesn't match with AppareilRoute?

Comment: Try making the matcher at the start of the url sufficiently different from the Controller/Action pattern, something like this: `url: "appareil-pages/{page}/{pageSize}/{triCol}"`

Comment: I tried this url: "Appareil/{page}/{pageSize}/{triCol}"
And now that works fine !!